# How to create raster from data (x,y,z in Cartesian coordinate System)?

Tags: raster, r, interpolation, spatial-statistics

I have simulated many trajectories of an moving object. From simulations I have obtained data files where the trajectory is saved in terms of x,y,z coordinates recorded at equal time intervals. Each recorded position also indicated the kinetic energy of my object. Sample data for first trajectory is below. All my data has been recorded in Cartesian coordinate System

```
      t        x      y        z     Etot
1  0.00 696621.4 167730 1680.960 1192.526
2  0.01 696621.4 167730 1680.959 1192.526
3  0.02 696621.4 167730 1680.958 1192.526
4  0.04 696621.4 167730 1680.952 1192.526
5  0.06 696621.4 167730 1680.942 1192.526
6  0.08 696621.4 167730 1680.929 1192.526
7  0.11 696621.4 167730 1680.901 1192.526
8  0.13 696621.4 167730 1680.877 1192.526
9  0.15 696621.4 167730 1680.850 1192.526
10 0.16 696621.4 167730 1680.834 1192.526
```

Now, I would like to create a raster file from the simulated data (2m DEM). The desired output is the object spatial frequency, aka assign a probability to each pixel of the object passing though it?

I have been trying to work by way through the *Applied Spatial Data Analysis in R* book, but i get stuck, i have never worked with spatial data before.

**QUESTIONS:**

- whats the easiest way to achieve my objective?
- which R functions/packages should I use?
- do I need to assign a CRS ?

**EDIT (adding info)** :
x,y,z ale coordinates from a 3-D cartesian coordinate system and describe the trajectory of a moving object. I have discarded a z dimension (height) and only plotted the positions of the rock within a 2-D system :

[image]

I have 90 more trajectories (within this area). I want to visualize the spatial deposition patter -> see which pixels are more likely to be hit by the object or not.

I was thinking of proceding:

1. Create an empty raster cell with 2m resolution
2. Overlay the 90 trajectories obtained from simulations (similar to Figure 1) and record how many times (and ideally with what energy) does a pixel get hit or trespassed.
3. Interpolate to empty cells
4. Resultant raster would express rockfall spatial frequency

[image]

Comment: Your [x,y] coordinates are uniform, it is impossible to create an nxn matrix with no dimensions.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans could you elaborate your comment? I am not sure I understand. What are uniform coordinates? What dimensions do I need to create an nxn matrix?

Comment: Could you explain more about what you have tried, and what steps you might use to get the desired result? Also, is your example representative of your actual dataset, with multiple repeated rows of data?

Comment: In this case, think of your [x,y] as the rows and columns of a matrix and your z value as the values filling the matrix. In your example data the matrix would have no row or columns. The [x,y] need to be unique values the equal the dimensions of the matrix. It looks like this data is a single trajectory and would need to be unstaked to represent a single row/column. When this requirement is met, coercing to a raster object is trivial. You can leave it as a matrix or use the raster package to handle single and multi band raster class objects and, no you do not need a CRS.

Comment: You are showing one value for "x" and one value for "y"... looks like a point with stacked "z" values. It may help to show other "xy" point values in your data.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans maybe I have expressed myself badly. My data is recorded in a 3-D coordinate system

Comment: @Simbamangu I have added more details. Is more data needed?